# Angular UI Bootstrap errors: 'datepickerCtrl.modes is undefined' and 'datepickerCtrl.modes is undefined'

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Angular UI Bootstrap components and keep getting errors when I implement Accordion and Datepicker.

A link can be viewed at http://smarajit.com/POC/ng-bootstrap/

The accordions expand but specifically I get

> "Error: accordionCtrl.addGroup is not a function" for each accordion group...."

and for Datepicker

> "Error: datepickerCtrl.modes is undefined" for each instance...."

However, the tabs work fine.

Am doing something wrong in setting it up? I have AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.2 and ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js included. I have declared the module as 
    var ngUI = angular.module('nguiApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap' ]);

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Provide enough amount of code. Review this link for ng accordion http://plnkr.co/edit/n2rHuR?p=preview

Comment: Have figured out the problem. I was naming my app's controllers as 'AccordionController' and 'DatepickerController' which were the sme names as the controllers named by Angular UI Bootstrap. Hence they were conflicting.