# Angular UI - Bootstrap Accordion not working/dynamic ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-include

I have a problem with the Accordion:

I try to do pretty much the same what the [demo](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) shows, I have an **Array of objects**. Every object contains a string, which is the header **title**. It also contains a string which is the relative **path** to another HTML-File, which should be the content of the accordion-group.

```
$scope.groups = [{
    groupTitle: "Title1",
    templateUrl: "sites/file1.html"
}, {
    groupTitle: "Title2",
    templateUrl: "sites/file2.html"
}];
```

This code is in a controller called `AccordionController`.
In my HTML I have this code inside of my controller

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" heading="{{group.groupTitle}}">
        <div ng-include="group.templateUrl"></div>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

The ng-include and that stuff works, but the groups basically don't react on clicks to then open or close, I also tried to add the `is-open` directive. With the parameter I pointed to a boolean Array which changes the specific values on `ng-click`

The annoying thing - which I really don't understand anyway - is that all this works [here in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dbSNwVH0So4He5EKcIMB?p=preview)

I also linked

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
```

and added `bootstrap.ui` to my module.

I get the error-message: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the console when I load it.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the solution:

First of all, naming a controller `AccordionController` creates **conflicts** with angular ui bootstrap - an internal controller is named like this.

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it works fine for me.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionCtrl">
    <accordion class="accordion" close-others="oneAtATime">
        <accordion-group  ng-repeat="group in groups" is-open="status.isOpen[$index]" >
            <accordion-heading>
                {{group.groupTitle}} <i class="fa chevron-icon" ng-class="{'fa-chevron-down': status.isOpen[$index], 'fa-chevron-right': !status.isOpen[$index]}"></i>
            </accordion-heading>
            <div ng-include="group.templateUrl"></div>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

and of course the JS:

```
settings.controller('AccordionCtrl', ['$scope',
function ($scope) {
    $scope.oneAtATime = false;

    $scope.groups = [{
        groupTitle: "Test1",
        templateUrl: "file1.html"
    }, {
        groupTitle: "Test2",
        templateUrl: "file2.html"
    }, {
        groupTitle: "Test3",
        templateUrl: "file3.html"
    }];

    $scope.status = {
        isOpen: new Array($scope.groups.length)
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.status.isOpen.length; i++) {
        $scope.status.isOpen[i] = (i === 0);
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Forked your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uXMPC55bfuHVhYme8b0i?p=preview) . Loaded template file

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
      content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1',
      templateUrl: 'file1.html'
    },
    {
      title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
      content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2',
      templateUrl: 'file2.html'
    }
  ];
});


<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">

  <accordion>
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" heading="{{group.title}}">
      <div ng-include="group.templateUrl"></div>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. In plnkr it works fine - how I want it! Sadly, it does not work in my application. I have 2 Modules (`app` and `settings`) and in the accordion 3 Controllers with that scope. In both modules I added `bootstrap.ui` and the modules know wach other too

Comment: Of course, in NodeWebkit I get the Error as above in my question, I tried to make the accordion as standalone to get my Problem, in NodeWebkit I get the same Error. In Firefox I get: `Error: d.addGroup is not a function`. The last line of the Error (in Firefox) is: `"<div ng-repeat="group in groups" heading="{{group.groupTitle}}" class="panel panel-default ng-isolate-scope"`

Comment: have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903509/angular-ui-bootstrap-errors-datepickerctrl-modes-is-undefined-and-datepicker) ??

Comment: I tried a lot now - got it, I will post the answer here.
Thank you very very much

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there might be a simpler solution.

You can just make sure that the links don't propagate the URL change.

Add to the a tag onclick="return false;"

Source: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803955/angularjs-with-bootstrap-3-accordion-not-working-when-included-via-ng-view)